# Why was my question about tanks in Ukraine closed?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have a question about my Skeptics Stack Exchange post: [In 2024 why are there only 14 abrams in ukraine?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56575/in-2024-why-are-there-only-14-abrams-in-ukraine)

Why was it closed?

Comment: The question that is being asked about appears to be the second attempt of asking it but got deleted.

Answer (score 4):

Your question was poorly written and contained no notable claim that could be addressed. Furthermore, your subsequent comments added no clarity whatsoever to what you might be asking.

If you have a serious question, please review the guidelines for notable questions and try again.

Comment: To be more exact the claim needs to be something notable that can be referenced on the internet and not just a claim that the OP is making.